# java.lang.verifyerror on googleplayservices adView class instantiation

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, adview

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but I am still unable to resolve the problem. I try to add a banner ad to my app via an xml resource but when I switch from the xml view to the graphical layout or clean my project I get the following message: "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView failed to instantiate,

> java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 77."

Sometimes it will say the branch target is at 57.

I am using the **googleplayservices** sdk version **18**. 
I've tried using java `jdk 7u51` and currently 8u5. 
eclipse versions kepler and currently luna. 
I have compiled at java 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7.

1. I have tried adding the `adMob.jar` file to the build path. I have followed all the instructions by google (and all variations I have been able to find on this site) to the letter, but still no go. I have tried changing the parameter arguments for the default VM in the installed `JRE`s to `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier`.
2. I have tried adding the **googleplayservices** lib folder to the build path directly and by adding a libs folder and then putting it in there.
3. I have changed the order and export so that googleplayservices is at the top of my build path. I have tried adding the googleplayservices as a source folder.
4. Lastly, I have tried each one of these options separately and different combinations of them together.

I have been coding for over a year now and this is the first time I have not been able to get an answer that worked off this site.

Here's my xml file where my banner ad is placed:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="I used my real ad unit id her"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

    <rest of my layout here/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my package name"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>



<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:name="my main activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" android:configChanges="orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".HelpActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:configChanges="orientation"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SetTimeActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:configChanges="orientation"></activity>
</application>
```

This is the event details from the error log:

```
com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView failed to instantiate.

  java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 77
Exception Details:
Location:
  com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.onLayout(ZIIII)V @9: ifnull
Reason:
Expected stackmap frame at this location.
Bytecode:
0000000: 2a03 b600 153a 0619 06c6 0044 1906 b600
0000010: 0b10 089f 003a 1906 b600 0a36 0719 06b6
0000020: 0009 3608 1504 1c64 1507 6405 6c36 0915
0000030: 051d 6415 0864 056c 360a 1906 1509 150a
0000040: 1509 1507 6015 0a15 0860 b600 0cb1     

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:363)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:190)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:399)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:336)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:517)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.changed(GraphicalEditorPart.java:725)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.onTargetChange(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1196)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.onDescriptorsChanged(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:916)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegateInitUiRootNode(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:835)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$TargetListener.updateEditor(GraphicalEditorPart.java:953)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$TargetListener.onTargetLoaded(GraphicalEditorPart.java:917)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin$11.run(AdtPlugin.java:1749)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

And my version and build info:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -data C:\Users\"user name"\Desktop\"my" workspace -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
```

**Edit:** I decided to make a new android application project in a new workspace and add a banner ad to that, but it also gave me the same error as above.

Comment: Email me your images I will post them here for you. prem30488@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks. I just figured out how to add my code. Sorry this is my first time posting. I didn't realize that you had to indent 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an Issue 76114 opened for this with a workaround for Android Studio:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76114

To workaround the Eclipse SDK:

1. Edit SDK_HOME\eclipse\eclipse.ini
2. Add a new line with: 
       -XX:-UseSplitVerifier
3. Restart eclipse.

Comment: I tried the workaround for eclipse but no luck. Since then I have migrated all my projects to Android Studio. Thanks for the link to the issue too. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I worked to understand how to use the Google Play Services for a week. I really used to add the Admob for months. When Google told not to use Admob on 1 August I said Oh! Why? Anyway, first I updated all the SDK and ADT at Eclipse Luna. Then I created my project, imported Google Play Services lib to workspace and I added it through project properties>Android>Add>libs. I did not do sth like add to build path or etc. All of the important parts are in your "activity_main" files. I mean do not create a different class like ads or sth. Just add this code to your activity files:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

public class Sample extends Activity {
AdView adView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I hope it helps to all.

Comment: Currently all my code is exactly as you have above. I get an error though because I do not have an R.id.adView. When I use the code from the google adMob example I get "No fill from ad server. Failed to load ad: 3." I made sure that my adMob is configured correctly so I know I don't have any problems there. I also added my actual phone as a test device and I get all the same errors. So it's not the emulator.

Comment: I actually run the app with the ad set in test mode and it still doesn't fill. So I think it's more than just that error, but I don't have anything else to help me figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have posted is an error within Eclipse.
It will not stop your application from running.

"No fill from ad server" means that your app is working correctly but there is no ads available to show. It is a normal message.